# datatable scroll

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a dataTable and I am using scrollBar if the records exceed ,lets say 20. The problem is after post back the div scroll bar goes to top. Is there anyway I can fix the resetting of scroll of div after post back. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get and set the element's current scroll position in Javascript using [`element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop). Make use of the form's `onsubmit` handler to save it as a hidden input element:

```
<h:form id="formId" onsubmit="saveScrollPos()">
    <h:inputHidden id="scrollPos" />
    ...
```

with this function

```
function saveScrollPos() {
    var scrollPos = document.getElementById('divId').scrollTop;
    document.getElementById('formId:scrollPos').value = scrollPos;
}
```

This way it's available as request parameter with the name `formId:scrollPos`. You can use Javascript to set it during onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var scrollPos = <h:outputText value="#{param['formId:scrollPos']}" />;
    document.getElementById('divId').scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

Here the `divId` is obviously the ID of the `<div>` you'd like to scroll.