# PrimeFaces dataTable scrollbar at desired position

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a scrollable dataTable with 100+ records when I add a new record (outside the default viewable area)and update the datatable the dataTable gets loaded from record 0, whereas I need datatable view at the previous position.

My dataTable code

```
<p:dataTable id="DataTable" value="#{dtMB.selectDataModel}" var="test" scrollable="TRUE" scrollHeight="500" styleClass="day-column2" selectionMode="single" >
 <ui:insert name="TableInsert" >
        <ui:include src="test.xhtml" />
 </ui:insert>   
</p:dataTable>
```

Command Button (inside a dialog) which updates the Datatable

```
<p:commandButton id="saveNew"  value="Save" type="submit" process="@parent" onsuccess="addNew.hide()"  action="#{dtMB.addNew()}"   update=":FORM:usrMsg :FORM:TABView:DataTable"/>
```

currently I need to scroll back to the n'th record to see what was added or do any updates etc.
Is there any option in primeface datatable, or I need to write a javascript for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the above using the following post

[primeface datatable scrollbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365873/primeface-datatable-scrollbar-position)

[datatable scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601171/datatable-scroll)

my code

script

```
function saveScrollPos() {
var scrollPos = jQuery('#receptionFORM\\:receptionTV\\:scheduleDataTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').prop('scrollTop');
document.getElementById('receptionFORM:scrollPos').value = scrollPos;
}

function autoScroll() {
var scrollPos = document.getElementById('receptionFORM:scrollPos').value;
jQuery('#receptionFORM\\:receptionTV\\:scheduleDataTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').animate({scrollTop:scrollPos}, scrollPos); 
}
```

HiddenInput

```
<h:inputHidden id="scrollPos" />
```

In Ajax event of datatable row select

```
onstart="saveScrollPos()"
```

The below code in CommandButton while saving record

```
oncomplete="autoScroll()"
```

Comment: helped me in fixing a bug. Always Thankful :)