# How to scroll to bottom of a JSF component after update?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a log that needs to be tailed in real-time:

```
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:100%; max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;" id="log" styleClass="logArea">
            <h:outputText value="#{myBean.log}" style="white-space:pre;"></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputScript>
        function scrollLog() {var log=jQuery('.logArea');log.scrollTop(log.scrollHeight-log.height);};</h:outputScript>
        <p:remoteCommand name="getLog" process="@this" update="log" onsuccess="scrollLog();">
        </p:remoteCommand>
```

While the log output updates just fine after remoteCommand has been run it does not scroll to the bottom. I suspect my scrollLog() is called before partial update is applied, and the update resets scrollbar to the top.

I also tried the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery( function() { var log=jQuery('.logArea');log.animate({ scrollTop: log.scrollHeight}, 1000); });
```

but nothing seems to work.

How can I work around this and scroll to the bottom of the log after every update?

Comment: It seems like that should work... did you see this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430546/primeface-datatable-scrollbar-at-desired-position

Comment: You've a client side specific question. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator and therefore irrelevant to the concrete problem (you'd have had exactly the same problem when using e.g. PHP, ASP or whatever instead of JSF). It's therefore easier for client side (HTML/JS/jQuery) specialists to understand and answer the question if you omit the JSF part from the question. I.e. just post only the JSF-generated HTML output (if possible, in simplified form which you've tested in a plain vanilla `.html` file).

Comment: @BalusC I partially agree. The JS code I use (or the one suggested by @better_use_mkstemp) works on its own. However DOM tree is updated by PF client-side library, and it seems that it resets the scroll position after my JS code runs - hence the question...

Comment: You might want to reformulate the question to "How to invoke a JS function after DOM update by PF ajax?" as this has apparently nothing to do with the specific scrolling function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onsuccess` handler is invoked *directly after* the ajax response is successfully retrieved, but *before* the DOM is updated based on the ajax response.

You want to use `oncomplete` handler instead.

```
<p:remoteCommand ... oncomplete="someFunctionWhichNeedsToWorkWithUpdatedDOM()" />
```